# Tree Mortality Task Force and Attribute Tables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, layers, attribute-table

http://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/USFSTreeMortality_2016/MapServer

I am working on a project using California's Tree Mortality task force information. CalFire was really helpful by providing the GIS data available for download in the link above. It downloads as a layer file, however when I view it in ArcGIS 10.2 and use the identify feature, the information such as type of tree, cause of death, acres, etc is behind that layer. There isn't an option to see the attribute table so I am unable to clip or perform a union to output the data for what I am looking for - I'm trying to split it up by county, utility region, and Tier I hazard zone - another layer available for download on the Tree Mortality Website.

Comment: `It downloads as a layer file`, this statement doesn't appear to be correct rather the data is available as a layer (which is a different thing).  When I download the data using another GIS client, I can see the attribute table, is it really not possible in ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

The layer file points to a map service. Map services will display the features and (if permitted) allow the identify tool to show attributes for individual features. They do not allow you to change the symbology, copy features, or view the attribute table as a whole.

A feature service would allow you to copy, clip, access individual features, or change the symbology. I examined their server, and it does not appear that CalFire offers a feature service of this data to the public.